# Two sentence answer, but seems good enough - how do I review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I came across this answer in a review:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12352465

The answer is basically two-line, the kind we usually see in comments; but I don't really think the person needs to supply more info. In other situations I'd downvote for being too short, but I really don't think that'd help here.

Am I missing something or do I just mark it as 'No action needed' and move on?

Comment: I'm almost sure any of the other 7 other answer said the same.

Comment: @Braiam, Yup, one right above it. And that too in 2013! Warrants deletion for sure.

Comment: see also: [There is no shame in using “Skip”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

Answer (score 1):

Some questions are really simple and a very short answer is perfectly fine for them. For example, see [the top answer for the second most upvoted [jquery] question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178450/3853934). In this case, even though the answer is short, is should still be an answer, not a comment.

However, in more complex question, short answers rarely give sufficient explanation, and therefore they should be comments.

As a rule of thumb: judge answers not just based on how much explanation they give, but how much explanation they give *relatively* to the need.

Comment: I have different concerns now, though. Two more similar answers have cropped up on that question, and the question is from 2010. Do we really need those extra answers?

Comment: @cst1992 If that answer doesn't add anything, it should be deleted.